# Arquillian persistence extension - @UsingDataset seed once for all tests

Tags: jboss-arquillian, dbunit

I have a JPA based application that is read only from the database, it therefore makes sense only to seed the database once before the tests start. Is it possible to do this using the Arquillian persistence extension? I believe it is trying to reseed/clean for every test?

I have tried the following

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@UsingDataset("mydataset.xml")
@Cleanup(phase = TestExecutionPhase.NONE)
public class MyArquillianTest {

    //Deployable method and tests
}
```

I've also set the `defaultDataSeedStrategy` to `REFRESH` in the arquillian.xml.